# JQuery mobile wordwrap inside <h*> tags

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have the following jquery mobile code:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3>I like to read a lot but sometimes I simply can't bring myself to do it</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi iaculis interdum felis, et tempor nunc commodo sit amet. Ut fringilla.  
</p></div>
```

I need the h3 tag to word wrap as opposed to truncating as jquery mobile does by default.

I've tried changing the above h3 tag to:

```
<h3 style="white-space:normal;">
```

or adding the following to the style sheet

```
h3  { white-space:normal; }
```

or

```
.h3  { white-space:normal; }
```

None of which works...any ideas? I could wrap it with line breaks but that's no good as it looks ugly if someone changes the orientation of their phone.

Thanks

Darren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had the right idea.  JQM just does some funky markup and you were targeting the wrong thing in the end.

```
 .ui-collapsible h3 .ui-btn-text{white-space:normal;}
```

Comment: Using .ui-btn replace .ui-btn-text for new version